# Can two waves be considered in phase if the phase angle is a multiple of 2$\pi$?

Tags: optics, waves, terminology, geometric-optics

Question is essentially what the title states. Wavefront is defined as the locus of points that are in phase. So I wanted to know if the locus would be the points of only a single circle or multiple circles whose points all have the same displacement? Or in other words can all the points that are at the peak at a specific time be considered as part of a single wavefront/inphase?

[image]

Can all the points in all the green circles be said to be in phase? Can they be said to be in the same wavefront?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*In phase* means that the oscillations are at the same stage in their cycle at the same time. So if, at a given instant, the phase angle – for example $2\pi\left(\frac tT-\frac r{\lambda}-\text{constant}\right)$ – differs by $2\pi n$ for $n=0, ±1, ±2...$ at two points in the path of the wave, the oscillations are in phase at these points.

We say that the points are on the same *wavefront* only if the phase angle at any instant is the same ($n=0$). This usually means that the locus of such points is one continuous line or surface. The points are on different but in-phase wavefronts if the phase angle differs by $2\pi n$ in which $n≠0$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Two waves are in phase when phase difference is two pi. Out of phase when phase difference is one pi.

Comment: So what about the wavefronts whose phase difference is 2 pi? Are they considered to be the same wavefront?

Comment: What if the wave is a very short pulse?

Comment: It does not depend on the frequency, I presume.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the term wavefront is used to refer to the pulse that was produced by the source at the same time. So when we define wavefront we define it as a locus of points with same phase, where a phase difference of $2\pi$ is not considered in the locus.

All the points on the green circles are in phase but a single green circle is considered to be a wavefront.

Answer (score 1):

> Can two waves be considered in phase if the phase angle is a multiple of 2π ?

Yes. Common cases in modulus arithmetic :
$$ \begin{align}
 \phi \mod 360^{\circ} &= 0^{\circ} \to \text{in phase}\\
 \phi \mod 360^{\circ} &= 180^{\circ} \to \text{out of phase}\\
 \phi \mod 360^{\circ} &= 90^{\circ} \to \text{neither in phase, nor out of phase}
\end{align}
$$
And many of states in-between of these extremes.